# display of image requires two clics instead of one

Tags: image, android-intent, display

A piece of code I created to open an image requires that I click **twice** on the words to open the image. I don't understand why it doesn't respond to just **one** click.

In the layout here is the TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="The New Yorker"
    android:id="@+id/the_new_yorker"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:onClick="new_yorker_cartoon"/>
```

and here is the corresponding function in the java file

```
public void new_yorker_cartoon(View view) {
    final TextView TextGenerique = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_new_yorker);
    View.OnClickListener monEcouteur = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String imageUrl = "http://www.lapasserelle.com/english/l09/imgs/new_yorker.gif";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imageUrl), "image/gif");
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    TextGenerique.setOnClickListener(monEcouteur);
}
```

What I don't understand is why I need to click twice on the words New Yorker to display the image new_yorker.gif on my phone.

Comment: try putting log statements in your onClick() method and see if they appear when you click once.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the first click is to activate the screen and the second to get the response.